# Adding a DOM element outside of the controllers scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular.js and wanted to try converting a control panel I'm making for a project to use Angular instead of jQuery.

Now all is well and it loads the items from the database using the $http service. And displays it correctly as a table using ng-repeat. But now I want to be able to click on the item and view it's details. I'm using windows to display the information like so http://prntscr.com/4ray0u (main window). When you click on the Items button it'll look like http://prntscr.com/4rayij (main & items window).

What I need some help with now is figuring out how to display a new window with the details of the clicked item. As all the windows are children of the body element it's outside of the controllers scope so I wouldn't be able to access those variables.

The base structure of the details window:

```
<div class="window">
    <hgroup>
        <h1></h1>
        <button class="close"><span class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></span></button>
    </hgroup>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is where [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements) comes in. You should look up existing code for modal dialog directives for AngularJS online, and just adapt them for your particular markup and use case.